# Game architecture in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, architecture, starling-framework

I now use starling framework to do a game in flash. However I am new to architecture in game and I think what I have done here in my game is not really good.

I have a Screen class which is used to display the content to stage.

```
public class Screen {
    private var button : Button
    private var controller : Controller

    public function Screen(){
       controller = new Controller(button)
    }
}

public class Button{
    private var controller : Controller
    private var button: Button

    public function Button(){
       button.addEventListener(Event.TRIGGERED, onTrigger)
    }

    private function onTrigger(e:Event){
       controller.notify(buttonTriggered);
    }
}
//in the controller class, I have a list of controller which controls other components 
//those are added to Screen class (character, ...) 
public class Controller{
   public function Controller(button){

   }

   public function notify(event){
      switch(event){
         //notify to other controller with this event
      }
   }
}
```

Do you have any suggestions for this architecture. Thank you very much for all of your feedbacks.

Comment: Remember to include the types you're expecting in your function arguments.

For example:
    public function Controller(button:Button) { ....

regarding the architecture it really depends on what you're trying to do

Comment: What I am trying to do is to create a list of controller that will control each component on screen (like button, hero. blah blah). All will be inside the Controller class. The Controller class will be like publisher, whenever events happen it will publish the event to the each component controller that needs the event

Answer (score 1):

I create a great solution for screens in [gazman-sdk.com](http://gazman-sdk.com).

When you think about screens mechanism what are it's main tasks:

- Managing a screens stack
- Informing the screens with stack changes:

  - call `on resume` when screen getting to the top of the stack
  - call `on pause` when screen is no longer on top of the stack
  - And call `on create` when screen is created and `dispose` when screen is destroyed.
- Also you want to encapsulate the screen logic inside the screen some how. So your code will not have lines like: `opneScreen(new GameScreen());`. Because the class who calling this method know who `GameScreen` is and you want to avoid this.
- And finally when your screens mechanism is up and running you don't want to write another identical mechanism for popups as it's pretty much the same.

I build a solution using [Multiton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern), it has multi-representation for screens stack model, that is used both for popups, and screens. Each screen is encapsulated and starts and closes by listening to system events.

Unfortunately I did not created a full tutorial for that yet. When I do it will be published [here](http://gazman-sdk.com/tutorials/). How ever I did a running example of this mechanism in my Component Explorer project. You can find it's source code on [github](https://github.com/Ilya-Gazman/gazman-sdk/tree/master/ComponenetExplorer). And live example at [here](http://gazman-sdk.com/explorer.php).

I am constantly active on this site so if you choose to implement it in your project I be able to help you with any questions you will have on the way.

Cheers and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

regarding your button class, i assume you want a button that can be clicked with the mouse. if that is the case, you should change Event.TRIGGERED to MouseEvent.CLICK, and the e:Event parameter in onTrigger to e:MouseEvent. Then the function will trigger whenever you click the button.

Comment: Because I use starling framework so there is no MouseEvent, I use trigger event instead. Thank you for your answer but what I want to ask is the structure of those classes, something like when I press the button, the event will be passed to controller and the controller will pass to all the components controller that listen to the event. And then those controller will update the components skin, text, etc ...